# Execute shell script in remote machine using ssh command with config file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, scp

I want to execute a shell script in remote machine and i achieved this using the below command,

```
ssh user@remote_machine "bash -s" < /usr/test.sh
```

The shell script executed properly in the remote machine. Now i have made some changes in script to get some values from the config file. The script contains the below lines,

```
#!bin/bash
source /usr/property.config
echo "testName"
```

**property.config :**

```
testName=xxx
testPwd=yyy
```

Now if i run the shell script in remote machine, i am getting no such file error since /usr/property.config will not be available in remote machine.

How to pass the config file along with the shell script to be executed in remote machine ?

Comment: Use [`scp`](http://man.cx/scp) ?

Comment: @anishsane : why use `scp` when the objective is not to copy?

Comment: scp is the most reliable way to get the file to target. There are other options, like sending it over `stdin` (`ssh user@remote_host 'cat >/path/to/config.file; /remote/command' < /local/config.file`), but scp is the most reliable way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only way you can reference to your `config` file that you created and still run your script is you need to put the config file at the required path there are two ways to do it.

1. If `config` is almost always fixed and you need not to change it, make the `config` locally on the host machine where you need to run the script then put the absolute path to the `config` file in your script and make sure the user running the script has permission to access it.
2. If need to ship your config file every time you want to run that script, then may just simply `scp` the file before you send and call the script.

   ```
   scp property.config user@remote_machine:/usr/property.config
   ssh user@remote_machine "bash -s" < /usr/test.sh
   ```

**Edit**

as per request if you want to forcefully do it in a single line this is how it can be done:

- property.config

  ```
  testName=xxx
  testPwd=yyy
  ```
- test.sh

  ```
  #!bin/bash
  #do not use this line source /usr/property.config
  echo "$testName"
  ```

Now you can run your command as John has suggested:

```
ssh user@remote_machine "bash -s" < <(cat /usr/property.config /usr/test.sh)
```

Comment: Thanks.. #2 requires to execute multiple command.. is it possible to combine as single command.,.?

Comment: You can do it like this `scp property.config user@remote_machine:/usr/property.config;ssh user@remote_machine "bash -s" < /usr/test.sh` but this is **cheating** if you really want to combine them as single command then you will have to `cat` the output of the `config` and `bash` script in single file (as @John has mentioned) that would take some small change in the source of `test.sh` if you want I can share that method as well, if you are interested in changing it.

Comment: thanks anand. I got it work as expected but still i am curious to get more options for this.. please share your methods.

Comment: @Jugi I have updated the answer to describe the other technique.

Comment: thanks.. My last question, how to pass an argument to that :( ?

Comment: @Jugi no need to pass any argument since `config` file (I assume it is also written in the bash scripting syntax) has been concatenated with `bash` script into a single self contained script, which can be executed on the remote machine without nay dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
ssh user@remote_machine "bash -s" < <(cat /usr/property.config /usr/test.sh)
```

Then your script should not source the config internally.

---

**Second option**, if all you need to pass are environment variables:

There are a few techniques described here: https://superuser.com/questions/48783/how-can-i-pass-an-environment-variable-through-an-ssh-command

My favorite one is perhaps the simplest:

```
ssh user@remote_machine VAR1=val1 VAR2=val2 bash -s < /usr/test.sh
```

This of course means you'll need to build up the environment variable assignments from your local config file, but hopefully that's straightforward.

Comment: Thanks.. config file contains contains more set of property values. It is just like a wrapper config file to define all the values in the config file and execute the script based on that. passing all these values as arguments seems to be bit tough

Comment: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('. Getting this error while running `ssh user@remote_machine "bash -s" < (cat source /usr/property.config /usr/test.sh)`

Comment: @anishsane second line should be `ssh user@remote_machine "bash -s" < <(cat  /usr/property.config /usr/test.sh)`  **source** is undefined and cannot be used like that, I would assume that a typo.